# XAML - How to declare Behaviours at Page or App level

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I've added the following behaviours to a custom user control in a WinPhone8.1 App using Blend:

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior x:Name="Pressed" EventName="PointerPressed">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background">
                    <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF75807F"/>
                    </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior x:Name="Released" EventName="PointerCaptureLost">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

This line was also added to my UserControl XAML:

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

This is fine and it works well. I was hoping to move this code into App.xaml so I could add the behaviours on to different Grids.

I moved the "using" statement to the App.xaml file: 
    `xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"` and also the Style:

```
<Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="ClickableGrid2" >
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior x:Name="Pressed" EventName="PointerPressed">
        <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF75807F"/>
            </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
        </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior x:Name="Released" EventName="PointerCaptureLost">
        <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background"/>
    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

I also referenced the style in my Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="QuestionGrid" Background="White" Style="{StaticResource ClickableGrid2}">
    controls omitted...
</Grid>
```

The code compiles but when I run in debug mode I get the following error as soon as the app starts:

> Cannot deserialize XBF metadata type list as '%1' was not found in namespace '%0'. [Line: 0 Position: 0]

There's no inner exception. There's not much detail, but I'm assuming the error is related to the "using" statements I added to the App.xaml file - but I'm not sure...?

I would assume Behaviours can be added at the app level but Google doesn't return any good examples of this being done. I have added simple Styles at app level and they work fine.

My question is: Can I add behaviours in this way, and if I can, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you can add behaviors to styles?

Comment: I'm not sure at all - It was my attempt at getting "global" behaviours to work, and there were no compile time errors so I thought I'd nailed it - until I came to run the app. There must be some way of having "global" behaviours but I could figure it out - I've left them local to the lists for now.